# IPython Notebook Extensions hide_input_all can toggle input cells off in notebook they still show up in Gist?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to share some plots I have created in an ipython/jupyter notebook with colleagues who do not need to see the code that created them. I successfully (after some trial and tribulation) installed this extension https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/hide_input_all which hides the code in the jupyter notebook but then when I create a gist link using the 'gist_it' extension or by copying the .ipynb file to gist manually it still shows all the code.

Is that how this is supposed to work or am I missing something? Seems to me the time when I would actually want to hide all of my input code is with nbviewer when I want to share it? not in the notebook when I'm writing the code...